# TF GET Won't Repopulate Directory

Tags: tfs, get, tf-cli

I set up my TFS Workspace and did `TF GET`, which downloaded huge quantities of files, exactly as expected.

Then I wanted to trim my local copy down to just the folders I was supposed to work with.  So I deleted all the others on my local copy of the workspace (not using TF commands, just Windows and DOS commands)

One of those directories has been added to my list of things to work on.

How do I get that directory back without re-downloading *everything*?

```
C:
cd \TFS
TF GET Zebra
(All Files are up to date)
```

All my non-existant files are apparently up to date with the extant files on the TF server.
I am baffled how `FileExists` is equal to `FileNotExists`!

After trying about twenty or so variations of this approach, I surrendered.

```
C:
cd \TFS
TF GET /FORCE
```

It's downloading a metric ton of stuff.  As far as I can tell, it's downloading everything.  Funny that the format of the output is different than my original `TF GET` (but that's really a distraction from the question, which is repeated below).

How do I get TFS to only download the current stuff from the Zebra folder and thus repopulate it so what I have actually matches the server?

And I suppose a side question - If deleting the files without telling TFS about it was the wrong way to clear up the space on my local disk, what should my approach have been?

Sorry if the question is noob-like.  But I guess when it comes to TFS I am, in fact, a noob.

Comment: There is a hidden folder at the root of your workspace mapping labeled `$tf` that stores information about the files (i.e. what version you have, whether you have it, etc.). Do you know if you have a local workspace or a server workspace (local workspaces only exist on TFS 2012)?

Comment: Not sure; we are on Visual Studio 2010, so guessing it is a server workspace -- which is funny when you consider the files are on my local system.  With all the "hide files" options turned off in Windows explorer, I can find nothing called `$tf` either in C:\ or C:\TFS, so I guess that supports your assessment about it being server-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TFS2010 you will have a server-based workspace, which means the server stores information about your workspace. These information include which files with which version you already downloaded. If you delete them using command line or Windows Explorer, TFS wouldn't recognize your changes. If you then do a "Get Latest" it checks the actual versions of files with the version you should (!) have. So if there is nothing new, TFS will not sent you anything, because it should be already there.

You can use the force option, so you would get the newest files no matter what is already in your workspace (or not)

```
C:
cd \TFS
TF GET Zebra /FORCE
```

The problem you face is a result of your workspace mapping, but this depends on how you are working. For example I'm TFS Admin, so I have one workspace for a whole TeamProjectCollection and never did a recursive Get Latest, I only get those files/folders I need. You could do the same with your TeamProject, but then you always need to use VS Source Control Explorer or command line for specific folders, what is not very handy.
I would suggest to create a workspace for the branch/folder you are working and cloak the folders you don't need. In this case you can do a GetLastest on your root, but still only get the files you are interested in.

Comment: Mike, thanks -- raises more questions from this noob, however.  The only references to "cloak" I can find are on the `TF WORKFOLD` command, and it appears I can cloak and uncloak server folders.  I suppose this means I would cloak all the folders, then uncloak the ones I want, then do the `TF GET /FORCE`.  I further suppose it is left as an exercise for me to figure out how to get a list of all the folders whose cloaked and uncloaked status needs to be ascertained or adjusted, which I don't mind doing -- so long as I am reading you correctly.

Comment: Sorry Steven, maybe this site will give you a better understanding about cloaking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378(v=vs.110).aspx
`TF WORKFOLD` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6(v=vs.100).aspx) could be used to modify your existing workspace, for example (you must be in the workspace root folder): `tf workfold /cloak $/ZEBRA_Parallel`
This should cloak the ZEBRA_Parallel folder from your workspace, so that it is ignored by Get Latest

Comment: You can also manage your cloaks in a dialog by running the "tf workspace" command.  It will open a dialog that has the full list of your workspace mappings.  A mapping can be an "active" mapping (which means files it represents will be downloaded) or a "cloak" mapping (which means those files will not be downloaded).

Comment: Many thanks -- I'm now clipping along in a very much less noob-like manner.  

I love this site!